# how to return vector by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

this is my simple code to return vector by reference:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
    vector<int>& VECTORTEST(){
        vector<int> v;
        v.push_back(10);
        v.push_back(20);
        return v;
    }
    int main()
    {
     vector<int> x = VECTORTEST();

        return 0;
    }
```

But I am getting segmentation fault when run this code. Any idea?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: What gave you the impression you should be returning by reference?

Comment: You should not do this. Any of this. `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is horribly non-standard, and returning a reference to an object with automatic storage duration simply will not work.

Comment: And when you couple [`<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) with [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) it's a quick recipe for name collisions.

Comment: Just return it by value. If you are using a modern C++ version, you will get an automatic move which is not (that) expensive.

Comment: The reason is that you are returning a reference to a (possibly) corrupted object. Vectors are automatically deleted on scope exit. And you do access that object. Because `vector<int> x = VECTORTEST();` does a copy. In other words `v` no longer exists when you try to copy it to `x`. Don't ever return by reference unless you're a ninja.